# How to delete all the iptables records created when the node was part of a k8s cluster?

Tags: iptables

This is a continuation to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055121/can-i-remove-multiple-matching-rules-with-the-iptables-delete-command

The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53404390/80002 is very useful - I was able to delete most of the entries. However, some entries are still there, but they do not look like ordinary rules:

```
student@worker:~$ sudo iptables-save | grep -iE "kub|cali"
:cali-OUTPUT - [0:0]
:cali-PREROUTING - [0:0]
:cali-from-host-endpoint - [0:0]
:cali-rpf-skip - [0:0]
:cali-to-host-endpoint - [0:0]
:KUBE-IPTABLES-HINT - [0:0]
:KUBE-KUBELET-CANARY - [0:0]
:KUBE-PROXY-CANARY - [0:0]
:cali-POSTROUTING - [0:0]
...
:cali-fip-snat - [0:0]
:cali-nat-outgoing - [0:0]
student@worker:~$
```

There are all in all 54 records like them. They do not look like rules. What are they? How can they be purged?

Comment: Why not just flush all the rules, and then set up your desired configuration?

Comment: I do not know how to do it. I do not know what rules should be there. I only know which should not, so I want to remove just them.

Comment: @larsks - I did some reading and I understand what you mean. I am OK with flushing. I actually found on the internet how to flush iptables. But I prefer you answering it, so that I could credit you.